# Generate menu dynamically using c# in asp.net with css for parent and sub menu

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, menu, webforms

I generate following structure for menu dynamically using recursive function.

```
<ul >
  <li><a href="/en/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/en/">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu2/">Menu 2</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Menu 2.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Menu 2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu3/">Menu 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu4/">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu5">Menu 5</a>
    <ul >
      <li><a href="">Menu 5.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Menu 5.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu6/">Menu 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to generate same with saperate class for parent menu &  sub menu as

```
<ul class="nav parent-menu">
  <li><a href="/en/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/en/">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown" ><a href="/en/menu2/">Menu 2</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Menu 2.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Menu 2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu3/">Menu 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu4/">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="/en/menu5">Menu 5</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Menu 5.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Menu 5.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu6/">Menu 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to add three different classes `nav parent-menu` `class="dropdown"`  `class="sub-menu"`

**C# Code**
Not sure where i should should change the code to make it work.

```
private string GenerateMenu(DataRow[] menu, DataTable table, StringBuilder sb)
{

    sb.AppendLine("<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>");
    if (menu.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in menu)
        {
            string menuName = dr["MenuName"].ToString();
            string menuURL = dr["MenuURL"].ToString();
            string line = string.Empty;
            line = String.Format(@"<li><a href=" + menuURL + ">" + menuName + "</a>", handler, menuName);
            sb.Append(line);

            string pid = dr["MenuId"].ToString();
            string parentId = dr["MenuInheritance"].ToString();

            DataRow[] subMenu = table.Select(String.Format("MenuInheritance = {0}", pid));

            if (subMenu.Length > 0 && !pid.Equals(parentId))
            {
                var subMenuBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(GenerateMenu(subMenu, table, subMenuBuilder));
            }
            sb.Append("</li>");
        }
    }
    sb.Append("</ul>");
    return sb.ToString();

}


//Call Function
GenerateMobileUL(parentMenus, table, sbMobile);
```

**Table Structure**

```
MenuID
MenuName
MenuURL
MenuInheritance
MenuNewPage
```

Answer (score 1):

**Copy And Paste and name it as Menu.css**

```css
#cssmenu {
  position: relative; 
  background:#DCDCDC;
  width:100%;
  
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background:Skyblue;
  width: 100%;
  
  
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
  
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
  
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}
#cssmenu > ul > #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family:Times New Roman;
  text-decoration: none;
 
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  color: Black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 32px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu li.has-sub::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub::after {
  right: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #7a8189;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover::after {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#indicatorContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
#pIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  z-index: -2;
  -webkit-transition: left .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: left .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: left .25s ease;
  -o-transition: left .25s ease;
  transition: left .25s ease;
}
#cIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  top: -12px;
  right: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 37px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  top: 44px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  width: 130px;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: Black;
  background:#DCDCDC;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease;
  transition: all .35s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #8c9195;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: '';
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: 10px;
  top: 12px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease, right 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  right: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  left: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenuArrow,
  #cssmenu #indicatorContainer {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu li,
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    right: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul .has-sub::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
    background: none;
    color: #8c9195;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 50px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 65px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 80px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 95px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > #menu-button {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button > a {
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul.open li,
  #cssmenu > ul.open > li {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open > li#menu-button > a {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 0px solid #7a8189;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #7a8189;
    right: 20px;
    top: 15px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 0px solid #7a8189;
    right: 20px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul.open #menu-button::after,
  #cssmenu ul.open #menu-button::before {
    border-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

**In form**

```
<table width="100%">
        <td style="width: 200px" valign="top">
            <div id="cssmenu">
                <ul id="">
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Admin</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Test1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Master</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>test</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Test2</a>
                            <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Test2-test</a>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </table>
```

**Use For Has Sub else Avoid**

```
    <script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="indicatorContainer"><div id="pIndicator"><div id="cIndicator"></div></div></div>');
            var activeElement = $('#cssmenu>ul>li:first');

            $('#cssmenu>ul>li').each(function() {
                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    activeElement = $(this);
                }
            });


            var posLeft = activeElement.position().left;
            var elementWidth = activeElement.width();
            posLeft = posLeft + elementWidth / 2 - 6;
            if (activeElement.hasClass('has-sub')) {
                posLeft -= 6;
            }

            $('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
            var element, leftPos, indicator = $('#cssmenu pIndicator');

            $("#cssmenu>ul>li").hover(function() {
                element = $(this);
                var w = element.width();
                if ($(this).hasClass('has-sub')) {
                    leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 12;
                }
                else {
                    leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 6;
                }

                $('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', leftPos);
            }
, function() {
    $('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
});

            $('#cssmenu>ul').prepend('<li id="menu-button"><a>Menu</a></li>');
            $("#menu-button").click(function() {
                if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: @Kartheyan, I am already doing it in a similar for other project, but i want to do it in C# codebehind. I know this approach is not very good approach but i am trying to do it this way. right now i am generating clean menu structure and adding class using jquery which works fine

Comment: i know men your try code behind but try this way you can use much of sub menus and menus you want :)

Comment: Thanks, I am doing something similar with using following https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMrqmQ

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Page Permission Comfig Form</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <label>User Type
                       <select id="txtusertype" class="form-control">
                            <option value="ALL">Select user type</option>
                        </select>
                            </label>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" >
                         <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="getlist">

                         </div>

                             </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                         <input type="button" class="btn btn-success " value="Save" onclick="SaveRecords();" />
                         </div>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="MailMenuList" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="SubMenuList" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 //page load function
    $(document).ready(function () {

        getusertype();
        GetPagNameAll();
    })


    //get all page name in db menu and sub menu type display
    function GetPagNameAll() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/PagePermission/PagePermission.aspx/getDisplayALLPageName",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

                var jsdata = JSON.parse(msg.d);
               // var SubMenu = jsdata.SubMenuList;
                $.each(jsdata, function (key, value) {
                    $("#MailMenuList").val(value.mainmenulist);
                    $("#getlist").append('<ul   style="padding:5px"><li><input type="checkbox" id="main' + value.id + '" value="' + value.id + '" onclick="Maincheck_fun(' + value.id + ');"/>' + value.pagename)//onclick="checkSubMenufun(' + value.id + ');"     onclick="check_fun(\'' + value.id + ',' + value.SubMenuList +'\');"
                    //'<ul><input type="checkbox" id="' + value.id + '" value="' + value.pagename + '" />"' + value.pagename+'"'
                    var sub_length=value.SubMenuList.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < sub_length; i++) {
                        //'<li><input type="checkbox" id="' + value.id + '" value="' + value.pagename + '"  />"' + value.pagename+'"</li>'
                        $("#getlist").append('<ul><li><input type="checkbox" id="sub' + value.SubMenuList[i].id + '" class="cl_name' + value.id + '" value="' + value.SubMenuList[i].id + '" onclick="Subcheck_fun(' + value.id + ',' + value.SubMenuList[i].id + ');"/>' + value.SubMenuList[i].pagename + '</li><ul>')//onclick="checkUncheckMainMenufun(' + value.id + ',' + value.SubMenuList[i].id + ');"
                    }
                    '<li></ul>';

                });

            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert("failure");
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });




    }


    //get drop down values in db
    function getusertype() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/PagePermission/PagePermission.aspx/GetUserType",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#txtusertype').empty().append('<option value="ALL">Select user type</option>');
                var jsdata = JSON.parse(msg.d);
                $.each(jsdata, function (key, value) {

                    $('#txtusertype').append('<option value="' + value.Sno + '">' + value.pagename + '</option>');
                });
                //$(".side-menu").empty();
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert("failure");
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

#region Select Drobdowm List

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetUserType()
    {
        try
        {
            registerEntities1 db = new registerEntities1();
            var usertype = db.user_type_table.Select(x => new { x.user_id, x.user_name }).ToList();
            List<details> obj = new List<details>();

            foreach (var append in usertype)
            {
                details objd = new details();
                objd.pagename = append.user_name;
                objd.Sno = append.user_id.ToString();
                obj.Add(objd);
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer objsr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return objsr.Serialize(obj);
            //return "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region display all page name in page load
    [WebMethod]
    public static string getDisplayALLPageName()
    {
        registerEntities1 db = new registerEntities1();
        var main_menu_list = db.page_name_table.Select(x => new { x.page_id, x.page_name }).ToList();
        var sub_menu_list = db.page_name_submenu.Select(x => new { x.page_id, x.page_name, x.main_menu_id }).ToList();

        List<mainMenu> MainMenuList = new List<mainMenu>();


        foreach (var main_menu in main_menu_list)
        {
            List<subMenu> SubMenuList = new List<subMenu>();
            mainMenu mainMenuDetails = new mainMenu();
            foreach (var sub_menu in sub_menu_list)
            {
                subMenu sunMenuDetails = new subMenu();
                if (main_menu.page_id == sub_menu.main_menu_id)
                {
                    sunMenuDetails.id = sub_menu.page_id.ToString();
                    sunMenuDetails.pagename = sub_menu.page_name;
                    sunMenuDetails.menutype = "Sub menu";
                    //sunMenuDetails.submenulist = sub_menu_list.Count.ToString();
                    SubMenuList.Add(sunMenuDetails);
                }
            }

            mainMenuDetails.id = main_menu.page_id.ToString();
            mainMenuDetails.pagename = main_menu.page_name;
            mainMenuDetails.menutype = "main Menu";
            mainMenuDetails.SubMenuList = SubMenuList;
            mainMenuDetails.mainmenulist = main_menu_list.Count.ToString();
            MainMenuList.Add(mainMenuDetails);
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer objsr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return objsr.Serialize(MainMenuList);

    }
```

## endregion